# In public encryption, Are the public & private keys device specific?

Tags: encryption

If they are tied to just one specific device, when do they change?

If they are device specific, how is that I can check my email on multiple computers or smartphones? If each computer has a different public key and a different private key, how can each successfully decrypt the message?

Sorry if this question is layman.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about security and not programming

Comment: Are authenticating to your mail server with a client certificate or why do you specifically show that example? This usually works with username&password that are securely send using SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good explanations online of public key cryptography. [This is a pretty good one](https://medium.com/@vrypan/explaining-public-key-cryptography-to-non-geeks-f0994b3c2d5) I recently came across. The key thing to know about public key cryptography (without getting into a huge amount of detail) is that you have two keys: with your **public** key (which you can share, hence the name), I can encrypt things that can **only be opened with your private key**. Both you and the server have a public key, thus you can encrypt messages back and forth. This is encryption -- that is, it is entirely to keep the conversation between the server and client secret, and away from prying eyes.

This is entirely separate from the reason that you are able to log into a website from multiple devices! For this, you are typically using a password. That is what is common among all your devices that allows you to log in -- your input.

Answer (score 1):

No, key pairs are not tied to a device.

There are standards for the encoding and storing public and private key information so that a key pair can be exported from one application and imported into many others. Of course, not every application or operating system that might generate key pairs supports these standards or permit this operation, but most do.

Encrypted email is not commonplace, and even today, setting up email encryption is harder than it needs to be. So, if you (or your system administrator) didn't do anything deliberate, like generating a key pair, and purchasing a certificate for your public from a certifying authority, then exporting the key store to your various devices (or the analogous activities for PGP), I doubt you are using "encrypted email."

Most mail servers support "transport encryption", where TLS ("SSL") is used to keep your mail (and mail service password) private. But this is different than encrypted email. Encrypted email using S/MIME or PGP will protect your email while it's stored on servers or on your client, and on any links between mail servers that don't use TLS.